# Two get requests in one django APIView

Tags: python, django, rest

I have an APIView for a X object. I want to have a get request `get_X` (receives id of the X object) and a get request `get_multiple_X` (gets all X objects).

The current solution is: we have two APIView: one called `XView` (contains `get_X`), the second called `XListView` (contains `get_multiple_X`). 
Is there a way to make both requests in the same APIView? I want to have only one APIView (`XView`).

What is the best practice in this case?

Comment: You might want to consider using `ViewSet`s: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks! this seems exactly like what I need!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem actually this also separates the view to separate views at the end of the day, so I guess I better stay with the current solution because it's the same.

Comment: well usually it contains a lot of boilerplate code, such that the `ModelViewSet` usually only requires a model and serializer. Of course if the list is doing something completely different compared to the get, then then you can implement this differently. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I see what you say. The logic is not very complicated and the views sit in the same file. `modelviewset` seems interesting I will explore it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_X_common(request,id=''):  // the id will get in url
    if id:
       get_X() // get x single data using id 
    else:
       get_multiple_X() // get all data list
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good practice, but thanks for the help. I thought about it too, but I want two separate functions.

Comment: yes u can use two function. i also do like this in above code. get_X()  and get_multiple_X() are two separte function called in side a function

Comment: I think that two separate endpoints would be better, but I see what you are trying to solve. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using ViewSet instead of APIView, follow below example

**serializers.py**

```
class CategoryDetails(ViewSet):

    def get(self, request):
        category = Category.objects.all()
        serializer = CategorySerializer(category, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def categories_count(self, request):
        category = Category.objects.get(name="Men")
        serializer = CategorySerializer(category)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", CategoryDetails.as_view({"get": "get"})),
    path("categories_count/", CategoryDetails.as_view({"get": 
        "categories_count"})),
]
```